# How do I set a border for player.png on background.png

Tags: javascript

I need to set a border on background.png so player.png cant go past it or off of it. I used JS and HTML. Everything else works just fine, please answer as soon as possible. :)

Here is my code:

**Javascript:**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var background = new Image();
background.src = "images/background.png";
background.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    start();
}

var image = new Image();
var imageX = 0;
var imageY = 0;

function start(){
    image.src = "images/player.png";
    image.onload = function(){
        imageX = 35;
        imageY = 35;
        ctx.drawImage(image, imageX, imageY);
    };
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler);

function keyDownHandler(event){

    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    if (event.keyCode == 65) {
        imageX -= 13;
    } else if (event.keyCode == 87) {
        imageY -= 13;
    } else if (event.keyCode == 68) {
        imageX += 13;
    } else if (event.keyCode == 83) {
        imageY += 13;
    }  
    redraw();
}
function redraw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(image, imageX, imageY);
}
```

**Html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>blow shoot</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id= "myCanvas" width= "500" height= "250">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Images:**

[player.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxgjV.png)

[background.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mAse.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `strokeRect` function:

```
ctx.strokeRect(x,y,w,h)
```

where x,y is the coordinate of the left upper corner of the image, and the w,h is the dimension of the image.
If you want to make it stay out, `-1 on x,y` `+2 on w,h` to have a 1px offset on every side.

Comment: Where do I put it?

Comment: @CuriousFan7 You should put it in the draw function, after or before `ctx.drawImage`